# How can two web-applications, deployed on different application servers communicate via JMS

Tags: java, jms, jms-topic

I am having two java web applications deployed on different app-servers. I want to exchange messages between the two using JMS. I know how to do it for applications running under same app-server, but I cannot find any example for the applications distributed over different app-servers.

I am using Glassfish 4.1 as application server.

Comment: Using message driven beans? Or plain vanilla JMS API? Or...? In general it should not matter. You need to provide the message broker URL. The broker might be local to one of the applications and remote to the other, or remote to both if you are using an external broker.

Answer (score 0):

You can create queues with same names on both servers, and let the first queue push its messages to the second one using glassfish configuration, so let the imq brokers do the job. Configure the jms connection factory on the first server with the property "AddressList" with value "mq://host2:port2" with the settings for the second broker.

See the glassfish resource template for such a configuration in the OSCM Service Catalog https://github.com/servicecatalog/development/blob/master/oscm-installation/domains/bes_domain/installer/resources-template.xml

The example is the connection factory "jms/bss/masterIndexerQueueFactory" which you can find in this template.

More about the Open Source Project [OSCM Cloud Service Management Software](http://openservicecatalogmanager.org/ui/)